# Why the loss function can be apply on different size tensors

Tags: pytorch

For example, I have a net that take tensor [N, 7](N is the samples num) as input and tensor [N, 4] as output, the “4” represents the different classes’ probabilities.

And the training data’s labels are the form of tensor [N], from range 0 to 3(represent the ground-truth class).

Here’s my question, I’ve seen some demos, they directly apply the loss function on the output tensor and label tensor. I wonder why this can work, since they have different size, and there sizes seems don’t fit the “broadcasting semantics”.

Here’s the minimal demo.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

if __name__ == '__main__':
    features = torch.randn(2, 7)
    gt = torch.tensor([1, 1])
    model = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(7, 4),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(4, 4)
    )
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.005)
    f = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    for epoch in range(1000):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(features)
        loss = f(output, gt)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PyTorch the implementation is:

[image: pytorch cross entropy]

*Link to the Documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss*

---

So implementing this formula in pytorch you get:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

output = torch.tensor([ 0.1998, -0.2261, -0.0388,  0.1457])
target = torch.LongTensor([1])

# implementing the formula above
print('manual  cross-entropy:', (-output[target] + torch.log(torch.sum(torch.exp(output))))[0])

# calling build in cross entropy function to check the result
print('pytorch cross-entropy:', F.cross_entropy(output.unsqueeze(0), target))
```

**Output:**

```py
manual  cross-entropy: tensor(1.6462)
pytorch cross-entropy: tensor(1.6462)
```

---

I hope this helps!